# How to draw a triangle shape function plot with shape function area being (s, t,1 - s - t)

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method

I want to draw a dynamic graph showing the varying shape of a triangular element with the change in the point `P[x, y]` as shown below.

[image]

I want to find the shape functions with the varying value of P.

From areas we can write area coordinates as (s, t, 1 - s - t). As the sum of the ratios of the each individual area and total area should always be 1.

All this can be easily written as a triangle with areas s, t, 1 - s - t if the area of whole triangle is 1.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how barycentric coordinates in the triangle can be transformed to Cartesian coordinates and vice versa?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Henrik Schumacher, yes i want to know how barycentric coordinates can be transformed in terms of catersian coordinates.